# Android инструмент анализа запускаемых интентов сторонних приложений

Tags: android, adb

Необходимо отследить `API` сторонних приложений общающихся между собой посредством запуска `активити` с целевыми `интентами` и их параметрами. Нужно собственно собрать базу по `интентам` и параметрам.

Про `ADB` я помню, но как выделить и заставить писать логи запусков сторонних приложений? Подскажите кто как решал подобные задачи.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что ответ - никак. Даже рут, думается, не поможет. Чтобы как-то адекватно следить за работой приложения надо в него вшивать кучу данных для дебага. В релизных сборках, которые и живут в телефонах, этих данных и инструментов нет, их выпиливают специально чтобы всякие ушлые не смотрели что как работает и не искали уязвимости

Comment: Да можно и на эмуляторе запускать. Только вероятно сборку с полным дебагом системы надо, или `магический` ключ какой то включить - это предположение.

Comment: Не очень понимаю куак такое возможно. У вас на эмуляторе все еще полноценный андроид, и приложения там релизные. О каких ключах вы говорите?

Comment: Это теоретически возможно, приложение вызываемое через activity проходит через системный вызов, и если система собрана с дебагом, можно увидеть параметры вызова - это тоже предположение. На самом деле, я наверно знаю как попробовать решить эту проблему, попробую написать прокси приложение с парсером входных параметров по интенту. Удалю родное, поставлю свое, надеюсь получиться. ИД приложения, как и имя activity естественно такое-же как и у оригинала.